# How to call DELETE request method in Yesod?

Tags: rest, haskell, yesod

In the book on routing ( http://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers ) there's a paragraph:

> A separate handler for each request method will be the same, plus a
>   list of request methods. The request methods must be ALL CAPITAL
>   LETTERS. For example, /person/#String PersonR GET POST DELETE. In this
>   case, you would need to define the three handler functions getPersonR,
>   postPersonR and deletePersonR.

Performing something like

> curl -X DELETE localhost:3000/person/1

works, so the server is capable of handling these requests.

Several examples (like https://github.com/snoyberg/haskellers/blob/master/routes and http://pbrisbin.com/posts/posts_database ) use GET or POST requests (in stead of DELETE) to handle this.

Is there a straight-forward way to call the DELETE request from Yesod-code? So that the route handler `deletePersonR` gets called?

Comment: Can't you directly call `deletePersonR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the `GET` and `POST` methods, which can be accessed using plain links or forms on a page, `DELETE` methods require using JavaScript, and are not supported by all browsers. This is why `POST` is often used instead. To invoke a `DELETE` method from JavaScript, the easiest way is to use a JavaScript framework such as [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/person/1",
  type: "DELETE",
  success: function(html){
    alert("Ok, deleted");
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, if you generate this Javascript using Julius, you can use a type-safe URL instead of "/person/1".

Comment: PSA: This can be done without JavaScript if you use a form with a POST method, a button styled to look like a link, and [a method override](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.27/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-MethodOverride.html) from the `wai-extra` package.